# ffplay/ffmpeg on RTMP with H264-encoding

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, rtmp

I'm trying to play an RTMP encoded with h264 using the Flash Player 11 h264 encoder -
 with ffplay.

It works. But only if the stream is set with a bitrate of 64KB and the keyframe interval is 4.

 Otherwise it cant find any frames.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yay, it's finally working!

you need to set some options in the **application.xml** for the app that streams the video in the FMS, 

basically cancel-out things related to buffering:

```
[under StreamManager/Live:]

<AccumulatedIFrames>
   <MaxTime>0</MaxTime>
   <MaxSize>0</MaxSize>
</AccumulatedIFrames>
<Queue enabled="false">
   <stuff that doesn't matter when you set enabled above to 'false' />
</Queue>
```

Also, I think this helps too:

```
<Client>
   <MsgQueue>
      <Live>
         <MinBufferTime>0</MinBufferTime>
      </Live>
      <Server>
         <BufferRatio>0</BufferRatio>
      </Server>
    </MsgQueue> 
</Client>
```

Also, set **bufferTime** to 0 in the netstream object of the client that broadcasts the stream.